# Question in regards to a lower bound in the proof of a linear continuum is connected under ordered topology

Tags: general-topology

In the proof below, the author sets out to prove that if $X$ is a linear continuum, then $X$ is connected under the ordered topology:

> Suppose that $X$ is disconnected, then there exists two non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ separating $X$. Suppose $a\in U$, and suppose that $\exists b\in V(a<b)$. Let $Z=\{x\in V|x>a\}$, and contains $b$. Since $Z$ is bounded below by $a$, it has a greatest lower bound $z$.
>
> If $z\in U$, then since $U$ is open, there is an interval in $U$ containing $z$, which must, to exclude $b$, be of the form of $\{x\ |\ x<k\}$ or $\{x\ |\ j<x<k\}$ for some $k$ and perhaps $j$ in $U$. But then $\color{red}{\mathbf{k\ would\ be\ a\ lower\ bound\ of\ Z}}$, contradicting the fact that $z$ is the infimum of $Z$.

My question is why $k$ must be a lower bound of $Z$? I couldn't figure out why $k$ not being a lower bound of $Z$ will lead to some contradiction. In particular, is every element in $U$ implicitly a lower bound of $Z$ or $V$?

I think I am missing something obvious but can't figure out what. Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Source:
https://planetmath.org/aspaceisconnectedundertheorderedtopologyifandonlyifitisalinearcontinuum

Comment: I am already confused by "Since $Z$ is bounded below by $a$, it has $z=\sup Z$". I would say that $Z$ has a supremum if it is bounded above, not below.
I think this "proof" is quite weird...

Comment: @student91 my mistake, it should have been an infimum, let me correct my question. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now:

> Suppose that $X$ is disconnected, then there exists two non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ separating $X$. Suppose $a\in U$, and suppose that $\exists b\in V(a<b)$. Let $Z=\{x\in V|x>a\}$, and contains $b$. Since $Z$ is bounded below by $a$, it has a greatest lower bound $z$.
>
> If $z\in U$, then since $U$ is open, there is an interval in $U$ containing $z$, which must, to exclude $b$, be of the form of $\{x\ |\ x<k\}$ or $\{x\ |\ j<x<k\}$ for some $k$ and perhaps $j$ in $U$.

Let us call this interval $I$ for the moment. So $I\subseteq U$. Note that $Z\cap I=\varnothing$ because $U$ and $V\supseteq Z$ are disjunct.

Because $I$ is an interval, we have for $a,b\in I$ that $a<c<b\Rightarrow c\in I$. So all the numbers $\{x|z<x<k\}$ are also in $U$, and thus not in $Z$. So let $x\in Z$ be given, and assume $x<k$, then either $z<x<k$ or $x\leq z$. The first part gives $x\in U$ so $x\notin Z$ and the second part gives $x\notin Z$ by definition of $z$.

So indeed $k\leq x$ for all $x\in Z$, giving:

> But then $\color{red}{\mathbf{k\ would\ be\ a\ lower\ bound\ of\ Z}}$, contradicting the fact that $z$ is the infimum of $Z$.

Comment: By definition, $z$ is the infimum of the set $Z$, doesn't that lead to $z \le x$ in the first possibility?

Comment: Got it, since by hypothesis, $x \in Z$, $x$ can't be equal to $z$ which is residing in $U$. We can eliminate the equal sign in the inequality.